# cross account permission for s3:putObject is not working as expected

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Am trying to the test the s3 cross Account permission with instructions provided int the [S3 Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html).  In the documentation example Account A creates bucket policy with read access to Account B root. Account B created a user Dave and provided him Read Access on Account A bucket.

I have tried the above example and it perfectly worked fine for me. But when i try to use the same example for write access it doesnt work for me. For example in account A i created below bucket policy

```
     {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example permissions",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject"    
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

In Account B i created user Dave with below permission

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3: PutObject"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

But when i try to put object using User Dave credentials of Account B i get access denied.

Is this expected behaviour or am i missing some thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your user policy `s3: PutObject` shouldn't have a space in it.

Comment: hello Moe, that could be type while i posted in stackoverflow but ideally there was not space in iam. I actually used policy generator.

Comment: Can you try testing s3:* just to see if what you’ve done works? If it does, can you try s3:Put* and see if that works? If s3:PutObject isn’t working alone, you might just be missing a permission or two.